# How to save bmp-image, matlab

Tags: matlab

i have altered an image in matlab and now i want to write it to my file system.

my code looks like this right now:

```
save('newimage.bmp', 'newimage');
```

in the matlab program no error gets displayed.
But when i try to open the saved picture in my folder i get the error:
"Can't read file header!Unknown file format, empty/damaged file or file not found!"

so i tried the "imwrite"-function:
code:

```
imwrite(newimage , 'newimage.bmp');
```

but now i get plenty errors in matlab:

> "Warning: Data loss and unexpected results may occur with signed pixel
>   data.  In imwrite (line 447) In project (line 35)  Error using
>   writebmp (line 14)
>
> Expected X to be one of these types:
>
> logical, uint8, single, double Instead its type was int16.
>
> Error in imwrite (line 472)  feval(fmt_s.write, data, map, filename,
>   paramPairs{:}); "

I can't find the mistake. thanks for help in advance and sorry for poor english

Comment: Consider reading the error messages to find the mistake ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image is int16 type, adn bitmats do not support it, apparently.

Convert your image to another type to use `bmp` (or use `png`)

`imwrite(im2single(newimage) , 'newimage.bmp');`

or

`imwrite(im2double(newimage) , 'newimage.bmp');`

or

`imwrite(im2uint8(newimage) , 'newimage.bmp');`

Depending on your data and desired precission.